# AsymptoticLess function confusion

Tags: algorithm, computational-complexity, asymptotics

I have an algorithm which complexity is:

```
f[n_] := 1/2 (-1 + n) n + 1/2 (-1 + n) n (-1 + 1/2 (-1 + n) n) + 
  1/4 (-1 + n) n (-2 + 1/2 (-1 + n) n) (-1 + 1/2 (-1 + n) n) + 
  1/12 (-1 + n) n (-3 + 1/2 (-1 + n) n) (-2 + 1/2 (-1 + n) n) (-1 + 
     1/2 (-1 + n) n) + 
  1/48 (-1 + n) n (-4 + 1/2 (-1 + n) n) (-3 + 1/2 (-1 + n) n) (-2 + 
     1/2 (-1 + n) n) (-1 + 1/2 (-1 + n) n) + 
  6 Binomial[1/2 (-1 + n) n, 6] + 7 Binomial[1/2 (-1 + n) n, 7] + 
  8 Binomial[1/2 (-1 + n) n, 8] + 9 Binomial[1/2 (-1 + n) n, 9] + 
  10 Binomial[1/2 (-1 + n) n, 10]
```

I'd like to bound it for values of `3 <= n <= 10`. If I plot the function and go trial and error method I can see that for n <= 10, O(n^11) bounds f[n] just fine. However, if I evaluate:

```
AsymptoticLessEqual[f[n], g(x), n -> 10]
```

I get `True` every time, no matter what g(x) is. For example

```
AsymptoticLessEqual[f[n], n, n -> 10]
```

Will also output True. This is not the result I want because if I plot both functions, clearly `n` doesn't bound `f[n]` in the range previously mentioned.

In the end I'd like to prove that `f[n] = O(n^11)` or something among those lines. Am I using the wrong function or am I using it mistakenly?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `Expand[FunctionExpand[f[n]]]` will give a polynomial in `n`. As for bounding for `n<=10`, it is not clear to me that that makes sense. You can just evaluate`f[10]` and bound by a constant, for example.

Comment: This is what I needed, thank you!